# Get the current URL of InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

Is there a way in InfoPath 2010 to get the URL of the form which is published on a SharePoint site?
I know there are built-in functions for retrieving URLs of the sharepoint root site, the Sharepoint list of the form etc... but what I'm looking for is to get the full URL of the form, among with the querystring parameters?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the current URL includes the file name, if you know the file name and the current site, you can figure out the URL. I usually have my forms submit with a standard name made up of the user that was filling out the form, and a time stamp. I save that information in a hidden field, then when it comes time to submit I use that as the file name.

If you want the query string, that's another issue all together. Check out this blog post from the InfoPath team on how to pass in a query sting parameter (warning: only one paramater allowed) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form.aspx You have to host the InfoPath form in a webpart.

If you're willing to drop into code, there's more options for getting the current query string.

Comment: Since, I hadn't answer to the question till yesterday, I continued to search for solution and found the same post several days ago - so this is how I implemented it (and I will mark this as answer) although it is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Your code behind should have the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// NOTE: The following procedure is required by Microsoft Office InfoPath.
/// It can be modified using Microsoft Office InfoPath.
/// </summary>
private void InternalStartup()
{
    this.EventManager.FormEvents.Loading += this.FormEventsLoading;
}

private void FormEventsLoading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

The [LoadingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa943907.aspx) parameter can get you the querystring parameters as `value = e.InputParameters["Key"];`